# Mercurial Fails to Update to A Revision Due to a File Name

Tags: mercurial

I have a repository which I am trying to work on. Unfortunately when I `update` to a revision of interest it fails with message

```
abort: Illegal byte sequence: /Users/<user>/Projects/P/infusion16/Standings ? Kattis, Infusion Programming Contest 2016.pdf
```

When I run update with `--traceback` and `--debug` options it shows following:

```
File "/Users/evgeniy.sharapov/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/merge.py", line 1381, in batchget
    atomictemp=atomictemp)
File "/Users/evgeniy.sharapov/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/context.py", line 1969, in write
    **kwargs)
File "/Users/evgeniy.sharapov/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1115, in wwrite
    **kwargs)
File "/Users/evgeniy.sharapov/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/vfs.py", line 87, in write
    with self(path, 'wb', backgroundclose=backgroundclose, **kwargs) as fp:
File "/Users/evgeniy.sharapov/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/vfs.py", line 409, in __call__
  fp = util.posixfile(f, mode)

IOError: [Errno 92] Illegal byte sequence: '/Users/<user>/Projects/Puzzles/infusion16/Standings \x96 Kattis, Infusion Programming Contest 2016.pdf'
abort: Illegal byte sequence: /Users/<user>/Projects/Puzzles/infusion16/Standings ? Kattis, Infusion Programming Contest 2016.pdf
```

Looks like it has some sort of a character that is not supported in a file name ? I check environment both `LC_CTYPE` and `LANG` are set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

What could be done in this situation ? I could probably live without this file or have it renamed? Another problem that the fail in `update` happens in the middle of the process so I don't have all the files in the work directory.

Comment: What mercurial version are you using?

Comment: Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.5). Installed as a python module via pip.

Comment: Obviously there's an issue in Mercurial code with using deprecated functionality ( `utils.posixfile` ). I wonder if there's a remedy or workaround.

Comment: Since you're using the latest version of mercurial I'd suggest filing a bug on mercurial's bugzilla: bz.mercurial-scm.org.

Comment: Move the working tree to a Linux system. macOS does not accept non-UTF-8 file names.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first run `hg man` to obtain the relevant PATHNAME, and then extract that file's contents by: `hg cat PATHNAME`

Then you could try `hg revert --all --exclude PATHNAME` to extract everything else (assuming all the other filenames are accepted by the host OS).

Comment: Doesn't work, even with --exclude the error message is the same